# Does sc.parallelize() evaluate for for every action?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am looking for every action of my spark application to independently evaluate a function like this.

```
var count=0
def seqInt : Seq[Int] = {
  count=count+1
  Seq(count)
}


val rdd = sc.parallelize(seqInt)  
rdd.take(1)
#Should return 1
rdd.take(1)
#Should return 2
```

Is there any way spark can evaluate a function for every action called?

Comment: can you elaborate whats the point of this?

Comment: You should probably not used a `count` variable like this. Each of your Spark worker will declare its own field. I am not sure about what you want to achieve but if you want to share a mutable `count` variable, you could use an [Accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/Accumulator.html). Also, when you call `sc.parallelize(seqInt)` starting with 1, you are asking Spark to create an RDD from the Seq `(1)`. The method `seqInt` will not be called later when you perform a `take` action.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez I am looking for making an external web call for every query I run on the rdd. Any other way this can be achieved?

Comment: @mtoto does that instruction sc.parallelize run for every action built from that RDD or is it just a single scan and use the same RDD for subsequent actions?

Comment: ok, have you considered using a [`SparkListener`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener.html) to be notified of the completion of a task involving your RDD by Spark? This could be used as a trigger to make your calls?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez How can it help me to refresh  the data that I read from sc.parallelize()?  I want every action to automatically refresh the sequence that I am parallelizing in the above code.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand correctly. Is it something like `rdd.map(_.map(_ + 1))` you are looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156486/discussion-between-vishamdi-and-alexandre-dupriez).